# How to implement a regex in a if loop bash script?

Tags: regex, bash

I am writing a script using a function that is it supposed to install a package by giving to the function the name of the package.

I am asking to the user if he wants to install that packet and, to do so, I wrote a regex, but the thing is: my regex is ignored, I can write anything in the output it will works. Howewer, I want the user to write something specific in order to install the package.

```
#!/bin/bash

OK=$'\033[92m' #GREEN
BASIC=$'\033[96m' #BLUE
RESET=$'\033[0m' #RESET COLOR
CHECK_MARK=$'\033[0;32m\xE2\x9C\x94\033[0m' #CHECKMARK

function install_package() {
    answer=""
    while [[ ! ($answer =~ ^y$|Y$|Yes$|YES$|yes$|n$|N$|no$|No$|NO$|q$|Q$|Quit$|quit$) ]]
    do
        echo -en "${BASIC}Do you want to install $1 ? (y|n|q)${RESET}"
        answer=$(read) 
        if [[ $answer =~ ^y$|Y$|Yes$|YES$|yes$ ]]
        echo "test"
        then 
            echo -ne "${OK}Installation of $1 ${RESET}"
            apt-get install "$1" -y &>/dev/null
            echo -e "\\r${CHECK_MARK}${OK} $1 has been installed or is already installed. ${RESET}"
            break
        fi
    done

}

install_package "micro"

echo "test"
```

And my output:

```
root@test-deb:/home/user/bashthings# ./p.sh 
Do you want to install micro ? (y|n|q)y
test
✔ micro has been installed or is already installed. 
test
root@test-deb:/home/user/bashthings# ./p.sh 
Do you want to install micro ? (y|n|q)fege8geg655eg
test
✔ micro has been installed or is already installed. 
test
root@test-deb:/home/user/bashthings#
```

It might be confusing but what I am asking is why my regex is not filtering any of what I type ?

Comment: Please do not write output of `apt-get` to `/dev/null`. Write it to a log file instead, e.g. `apt-get install "$1" -y 2>&1 >> /var/log/my_script.log` and also output a message that tells the user that the log file is available. It will make problem resolution easier for the user.

Comment: And also, put `set -e` to the start of the script. It will terminate the script if an error occurs. (Or handle errors. `apt-get` can sometimes fail in very strange ways and for weird reasons. Misconfigured `dpkg` is frequent source of weird failures.) Instead of `set -e`, you can also add `-e` to the shebang line: `#! /bin/bash -e`

Comment: the `echo "test"` is between the `if` and its associated `then`; I'd have to think about that for a bit but I'm guessing this is treated similarly to `if [[ $answer =~ ... ]] || echo "test"; then ...`, and since `echo "$test"` is treated as 'true' the `then` block is always executed; move the `echo "$test"` somewhere else (eg, before the `if`; between the `then` and `fi`; after the `fi`) and see if your script now behaves as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `grep -q` (or `egrep -q` for extended version).

```
#            ↓ your string         ↓ the pattern
if printf %s "my_string" | grep -q '.*stri.*'
then
    echo foo
else
    echo bar
fi
```

Your `while` loop condition will look like this:

```
while printf %s $answer | grep -q '^y$|Y$|Yes$|YES$|yes$|n$|N$|no$|No$|NO$|q$|Q$|Quit$|quit$'
do
    : your loop contents here
done
```

---

In your conditions, you do not need to use regular expressions at all. Bash has neat syntax construct called `case` (similar to C `switch`):

```
read -p "${BASIC}Do you want to install $1 ? (y|n|q)${RESET}" answer
case "$answer" in
    [yY])
        echo -ne "${OK}Installation of $1 ${RESET}"
        # […]
        echo -e "\\r${CHECK_MARK}${OK} $1 has been installed or is already installed. ${RESET}"
        ;;
    [nN])
        : do nothing
        ;;
    [qQ])
        exit 0
esac
```

Case uses simple patterns. `y` means “exactly `y`”, you can use `[yY]` to provide multiple character variants. Separate multiple patterns by `|` for “or”. Asterisk (`*`) means “zero or more characters”, question mark (`?`) is one character.

Note also that I used `read -p PROMPT VAR` to read a text into a variable while displaying a prompt. See `read` help for more information, it provides quite a lot of features for reading text in such scripts.

Comment: I don't know that much about case I will look into it.

Comment: Okay, I see the thing but I want to add some flexibility for my user, like if they type Y or yes instead of y it will still works, and from what I understand here using case will match only one precise string

Comment: See the edits. Use `[yY]`.

Comment: Ouups my bad didn't see that ! I was trying to do like so but I still have some problems. I will try to solve them alone, I think you put me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I'd take advantage of [the `nocasematch` shell option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) that can compare
strings case-insensitively, and a `case` statement can add readability:

```sh
shopt -s nocasematch

function install_package() {
    local package=$1
    local answer

    while true; do
        echo -en "${BASIC}Do you want to install $package ? (y|n|q)${RESET}"
        read -r answer
        case $answer in
            n | no | q | quit)
                echo "ok, bye"
                exit
                ;;
            y | yes)
                echo -ne "${OK}Installation of $package ${RESET}"
                #apt-get install "$package" -y &>/dev/null
                echo -e "\\r${CHECK_MARK}${OK} $package has been installed or is already installed. ${RESET}"
                break
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

But the `select` statement is very useful for these kind of prompts: it
prints a menu and the user selects one of the options. It loops until the user enters a valid value.

```sh
function install_package() {
    local package=$1
    local answer

    printf "${BASIC}Do you want to install $package ?${RESET}\n"
    PS3="Your answer: "

    select answer in Yes No; do
        case $answer in
            No)
                echo "ok, bye"
                break
                ;;
            Yes)
                echo -ne "${OK}Installation of $package ${RESET}"
                #apt-get install "$package" -y &>/dev/null
                echo -e "\\r${CHECK_MARK}${OK} $package has been installed or is already installed. ${RESET}"
                break
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
```